# How to add Unique Id in polldaddy in a drupal block?

Tags: drupal, rating

I'd like to ad a unique ID to a drupal block for poll daddy rating. It's a video site, i'd like each rating to be for each video, hence I need to pull the video ID or node to the block. How can one achieve this, especially in PHP? Or other alternatives besides installing a module.

Comment: Your question is confusing.
Each block already has a unique id.
Are you talking about a html id attribute?

Comment: Yes I was. See solution below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After trying out a few things, this finally worked!

```
<?php print url(drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . arg(1)), array('absolute' => TRUE)); ?>
```